# How do I prevent my laptop from powering off when I hit the power button?

Tags: laptop, power, button-remapping

When I am working on my laptop, I usually work on the floor next to my file cabinet. However, sometimes I push my computer too far to the right, and accidentally hit the power button against the file cabinet, making it turn off. Also, when I a working on my desk, I also experience my computer turning off when the power button pushes against books on my desk, as well. Also, in in-person school, kids used to think it was real funny to just go around and turn off people's computers during lunch time. So, you can see that having a power button on the side of the laptop is a real inconvenience. I've tried putting tape on the power button, but when I apply the tape, it just turns off. Also, when I press on the tape, it still turns off. Is there anyway to edit the software of the computer to prevent it from taking inputs from the power button? By, the way, I do not need a power button, because I just use the windows menu to turn off my computer anyways.

Comment: Control Panel>Power Options>choose what the power button does. Set it to DO Nothing.

Comment: The above is a correct answer. You can also set it to suspend as that is less eventful and the button still serves a purpose.

Comment: I do not see a power options, all I see is "System&Security, User Accounts, Netowrk&Internet, Appearance&Personalization, Hardware&Sound, Clock&Region, Programs, EasyofAccess".

Comment: Open Control Panel and at the top right, change View By from Categories to Small Icons.  Then you will see Power Options as one of the selections to open. Then set "Choose what the power button does"

Comment: Note, though, that *holding* the power button for about 5 seconds should *always* cause an abrupt, complete power down. That's built into the hardware of all PC's I know of.

Comment: thats fine, I just only need it to not turn off on accident. Also, this is a school computer, so  the admin blocked me changing the power settings, thanks for the help anyways, though @John

Comment: and @Moab as well